# Sums of reciprocals

Tags: convergence-divergence

Suppose $n\ge2$ . Prove that neither

the sum  $\sum_{i=2}^n \frac{1}{i}$, nor the sum $\sum_{i=2}^n \frac{1}{2i+1}$

is an integer

The approach a tried to take, was to show that the denominator is never a divisor of the numerator, but I can't figure out how to generalise this for any n

Answer (score 7):

You can get around Bertrand's postulate for the first sum by looking at powers of $2$: let $k$ be the greatest integer such that $2^k \leq n$. Then $2^k$ divides exactly one denominator of the series, since the least proper integer multiple of $2^k$ is $2^{k+1}$, which is greater than $n$. Therefore when you put the series over a common denominator, the denominator is divisible by $2$ while the numerator is of the form $2a + 1$.

EDIT: In fact the argument works for the second sum as well, by looking at $3^k$ instead of $2^k$. The first two multiples of $3^k$ are $2\cdot 3^k$,which is even and so not in the series, and $3^{k+1}$, which is greater than $n$.

Comment: In fact, the argument works for $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{mi+1}$ for any positive integer $m$ for which $m+1$ is a prime or prime power, by looking at $(m+1)^k$.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the largest prime $p \leq n$. When you express $\sum_{i=2}^n \frac{1}{i}$ as a numerator with $n - 1$ terms over the denominator $1 \cdot 2 \cdot \ldots \cdot n$, all but one of the terms in the numerator is divisible by $p$, hence the numerator is not divisible by $p$, but the denominator is divisible by $p$. Therefore, $\sum_{i=2}^n \frac{1}{i}$ can't be an integer.

The same argument applies to the second sum.

Comment: Just for clarity: The fact that such $p$ occurs only once in the denominator requires Betrand's postulate - that there must be a prime between $n/2$ and $n$.

Comment: I'm sure the answer answer is great too, but this one made more sense to me. Thank you :)

Comment: @ferson2020 how would I prove that p divides all but one of the terms in the numerator?

Comment: Each of the $n$ terms in the numerator looks like  $2 \cdot 2 \cdot \ldots \cdot n$, but missing one of the terms. If $p$ is the largest prime less than $n$, and it is between $n/2$ and $n$, it doesn't divide any other number between $2$ and $n$. Therefore, $p$ doesn't divide the term in the numerator missing $p$ in the product, but every other term has a $p$ in the product, so $p$ divides every other term.

Comment: If you want to avoid the messiness of making sure $p$ doesn't divide any other number between $2$ and $n$ (the Betrand's postulate part), consider the largest prime power $p^k$ instead. I think it's easier to see $p^k$ doesn't divide any other number between $2$ and $n$.